# Extracting Action method args in c#

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following lambda:

```
public object Execute(Action<IMessage<object>> method)
{

}

obj.Execute(x => someObject.RunSomething(new SomeMessage{a = "b"}));
```

`SomeMessage` is implementing `IMessage<T>`

I would like inside Execute to get the params sent to `RunSomething`...
I'm looking for something like `method.Target as IMessage<object>` or method.Target as SomeMessage

How can that be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: I don't follow. `method` is a pointer to a method. If `Execute` were to invoke `method`, it would have to pass in the `IMessage<object>` itself: that becomes the `x` on your last line (which you then ignore)

Comment: @canton7 `SomeMessage` is implementing  `IMessage<T>`

Comment: maybe `typeof(x)`

Comment: Let's desugar your last line. `public void Generated(IMessage<object> message) { someObject.RunSomething(new SomeMessage{a="b"}); } ... obj.Execute(Generated)`. See how you're passing a method which accepts an `IMessage<object>`, but whose *body* calls `someObject.RunSomething`, passing in an entirely different message? You'd need to look inside the *body* of `method` to see what it's doing, and that's not an easy thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to achieve but isn't it more logic to have something like that ?

```
public object Execute(Action<IMessage<object>> method, IMessage<object> parameter)
{
   method(parameter);
}

obj.Execute(someObject.RunSomething, new SomeMessage{a= "b"});
```

In that case you receive the parameter you will pass to the function. So you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: If you really want you can pass "(x) => someObject.RunSomething(x))" instead of just "someObject.RunSomething". Both are function pointer.

Comment: But I don't think it makes sense to have a new lambda function when it's not needed.